# Update Membership Statuses

Tags: scheduled-job

I am using civi on wordpress 4.8.1

I just need to check something.

If I have a membership that expires tomorrow and *Update Membership Statuses* is not enabled to run Daily, will that person's profile still have an "**Active**" status when it expires tomorrow?

On the other hand, if I do enable *Update Membership Statuses*, will that person's membership profile status change to "**Expired**" tomorrow?

I am asking because the description for this job says "***WARNING***: Membership renewal reminders have been migrated to the Schedule Reminders functionality, which supports multiple renewal reminders.", so I not sure I should enable it at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the warning is about how Reminders are managed. In terms of the Scheduled Job - yes you need that enabled if you want to have the Membership Status automatically updating (and it would a rare situation you would not want this happening)